# Проблема с записью текста в PDF

Tags: java, android

У меня есть код для программы в который пользователь вводит текст и при нажатии на кнопку текст должен записаться в PDF файл но почему-то программа не работает.
Ругается на эту часть кода в MainActivity

```
        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED);
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
    Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
    v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
```

Можете помочь мне с этой проблемой.
Полный код MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText MyText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
    }
    public void CreatePDF(View view) throws IOException{
        PdfDocument IP31 = new PdfDocument();
        PdfDocument.PageInfo myPageinfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(300, 100, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page bestPage = IP31.startPage(myPageinfo);
        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        String bestString = MyText.getText().toString();
        int x = 20, y = 40;
        bestPage.getCanvas().drawText(bestString, x, y, myPaint);
        IP31.finishPage(bestPage);
        String bestPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File bestFile = new File(bestPath, "nam.pdf");
        IP31.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(bestFile));
        IP31.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Как именно "ругается"?

Comment: @woesss
Ну вот так 
На часть new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED);
Выдает вот такую ошибку: Value must be ≥ 0 (was -1)
На часть Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
Выдает вот такую ошибку: Incompatible types. Found: 'androidx.core.graphics.Insets', required: 'android.graphics.Insets'

Comment: @woesss
На часть v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
Выдает вот такую ошибку: Field requires API level 29 (current min is 27): `android.graphics.Insets#left` (и выдаёт точено такую же ошибку в top, right и bottom)

Comment: Вы перевести текст ошибки с английского не можете или что?